# Is there any quick way to solve this question?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a random variable with the following cumulative distribution function
$$F(x) =
\begin{cases}
\ {0},  & x<0 \\[2ex]
\ x^2, & \ 0\le x<\dfrac{1}{2}\\[2ex]
\ \dfrac{3}{4}, &\dfrac{1}{2}\le x< 1 \\[2ex]
\ 1 & x\ge1
\end{cases}$$

Find  $P(\dfrac{1}{4}<X<1)$

**My input**

Here I used $P(X\le x)= F(x) $ and $P(X< x)= F(x)^{*}$

At $\dfrac{1}{2}$ our pdf is discontinuous and in the interval $0\le x<\dfrac{1}{2}$ $f(x)$ is continuous and in $\dfrac{1}{2}\le x< 1 $ it is discrete. So

$P(\dfrac{1}{4}<X<\dfrac{1}{2})+P( \dfrac{1}{2}\le x< 1 )=F\bigg(\dfrac{1}{2}\bigg)^{*}-F\bigg(\dfrac{1}{4}\bigg)+F(1)^{*}-F\bigg(\dfrac{1}{2}\bigg) + P\bigg(X=\dfrac{1}{2}\bigg)$

$= F\bigg(\dfrac{1}{2}\bigg)^{*}-F\bigg(\dfrac{1}{4}\bigg)+F(1)^{*}-F\bigg(\dfrac{1}{2}\bigg) + F\bigg(\dfrac{1}{2}\bigg)-F\bigg(\dfrac{1}{2}\bigg)^{*}$

$=F(1)^{*}-F\bigg(\dfrac{1}{4}\bigg)=\dfrac{11}{16}$

So this question came in one mark. Is there any quick way to solve this ?

Comment: $P(1/4<X<1)=F(1)^{\ast}-F(1/4)$ by your definitions. The rest is redundant.

Comment: @metamorphy So it's always true if we have mixed distribution then valid too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P\left(\frac14<X<1\right)=P(X<1)-P\left(X\leq\frac14\right)=\lim_{x\to1-}F(x)-F\left(\frac14\right)=\frac34-\frac1{16}=\frac{11}{16}$$

Comment: Always valid no conditions about continuity, discontinuity, discrete or continuous?

Comment: Indeed always valid.

Comment: What will be the probability at $P(X=\dfrac{1}{2})$?

Comment: $P(X=\frac12)=P(X\leq\frac12)-P(X<\frac12)=F(\frac12)-\lim_{x\to\frac12-}F(x)=\frac34-\frac14=\frac12$

Comment: In your answer you wrote $P\bigg( X \le \dfrac{1}{4}\bigg)$ but  $P\bigg( X < \dfrac{1}{4}\bigg) $ is valid too write?

Comment: In general $P(a<X\leq b)=P(X\leq b)-P(X\leq a)=F(b)-F(a)$. But not $P(a<X\leq b)=P(X\leq b)-P(X<a)$ (unless you are certain that $P(X=a)=0$. In that special case $P(X\leq a)=P(X<a)$.